# C++ Inheritance and Polymorphism unknown output

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{ // Define a base class
public:
    virtual void Func1() = 0;
    virtual void Func2();
    virtual void Func3();
    void Func4();
};
class A : public Base
{ // Class A derives from Base
public:
    void Func2();
    virtual void Func4();
};
class B : public A
{// Class B derives from A
public:
    virtual void Func1();
    void Func2();
};
class C : public B
{ // Class C derives from B
public:
    virtual void Func1();
    virtual void Func4();
};
// Base Class Methods
void Base::Func2(){ cout << "Hello from Base::Func2()" << endl;}
void Base::Func3(){cout << "Hello from Base::Func3()" << endl;
Func1(); // DON’T MISS THIS CALL IN YOUR ANSWER
}
void Base::Func4(){ cout << "Hello from Base::Func4()" << endl;}
// Class A Methods
void A::Func2() { cout << "Hello from A::Func2()" << endl; }
void A::Func4() { cout << "Hello from A::Func4()" << endl; }
// Class B Methods
void B::Func1() { cout << "Hello from B::Func1()" << endl; }
void B::Func2() { cout << "Hello from B::Func2()" << endl; }
// Class C Methods
void C::Func1() { cout << "Hello from C::Func1()" << endl; }
void C::Func4() { cout << "Hello from C::Func4()" << endl; }
void TestFuncRef(Base& x)
{
    x.Func1();
    x.Func2();
    x.Func3();
    x.Func4();
}
void TestFuncVal(B x)
{
    x.Func1();
    x.Func2();
    x.Func3();
    x.Func4();
}
int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    TestFuncRef(c);
    TestFuncRef(b);
    TestFuncVal(c);
}
```

So right now I have the above code that focuses on inheritance and polymorphism. I need some help with understanding how parts of the outputs are achieved.

The outputs are:

```
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from B::Func2()
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
Hello from B::Func1()
Hello from B::Func2()
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from B::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
Hello from B::Func1()
Hello from B::Func2()
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from B::Func1()
Hello from A::Func4()
```

I don't understand how there are always some call between the base Func3 and Base func4 calls. Such as the following

```
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
```

and

```
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from B::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
```

Also could someone please explain to me how the TestFuncRef and TestFuncVal functions work? I don't get the outputs from those calls either. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling code is:

```
C c;
TestFuncRef(c);
```

And `TestFuncRef` upcasts `C` to `Base` and performs the following:

```
x.Func1();
x.Func2();
x.Func3();
x.Func4();
```

1. `Base::Func1` is virtual and `C::Func1` overrides it

   - outputs `"Hello from C::Func1()"`
2. `Base::Func2` is virtual and `C::Func2` is **NOT** implemented but `C` inherits from `B` and `B::Func2` overrides it

   - outputs `"Hello from B::Func2()"`
3. `Base::Func3` is virtual and `C::Func3` is **NOT** implemented but `C` inherits from `B` which inherits from `A` which inherits from `Base` and `Base::Func3` is implemented

   - outputs `"Hello from Base::Func3()"`
   - **THEN CALLS `Func1`** which is virtual (this is the same case as #1)

     - outputs `"Hello from C::Func1()"`
4. `Base::Func4` is **NOT** virtual therefore `Base::Func4` is called (not `C::Func4`)

   - outputs `"Hello from Base::Func4()"`

Therefore the expected output is:

```
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from B::Func2()
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
```

This is the exactly the first part of your output and is expected.

> I don't understand how there are always some call between the base Func3 and Base func4 calls. Such as the following.

```
Hello from Base::Func3()
Hello from C::Func1()
Hello from Base::Func4()
```

This is exactly what it was told to do and your question seems to indicate you know something like this is expected as it includes the following.

> void Base::Func3(){cout << "Hello from Base::Func3()" << endl;
>   Func1(); // DON’T MISS THIS CALL IN YOUR ANSWER
>   }

Which obviously performs a `Func1` operation during the `Func3` operation and in this case produces the output you observe.

> please explain to me how the TestFuncRef and TestFuncVal functions work

`TestFuncRef` is explained above.

```
TestFuncRef(b);
```

You should be able to trace this yourself in the same way as shown above.

```
TestFuncVal(c);
```

This introduces object slicing:

- [Wikipedia - Object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)
- [Stack Overflow - What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

### Edit

Your base class (`Base`) needs a virtual destructor (`virtual ~Base()`), see [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).